# Fill a DataRow from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm aware of retrieving SQL Server CE data into various data types such as strings, ints, dataTables etc etc. But in this case I'm cycling through an infragistics `SelectedRowsCollection` using a `foreach` loop and doing some checks on each record.

Based on the checks that I perform, I want some of these records to be added to a `DataTable`. What I'm doing is adding them to a table in my database, then selecting that information as a single row (there are other reasons for this, dont mind them). What is the best way of combining lots of single rows of data into on `DataTable`?

I tried to use a `SqlCeDataAdapter` fill function, but it does not contain an overload that handles a single `DataRow`. Any ideas?

I'm using SQL Server CE.

To summarize, my question is: how do I get a single row from SQL Server CE to be added as a row in a `DataTable`?

Comment: How do you actually add to the DataTable?, without seeing this bit of code is not possible to say if you have done well or not.

Comment: Adding to a datatable is what I'm trying to achieve, it is not what I have already done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

This is probably your easiest method if you are building individual rows.

You could also use:

```
dt.Rows.Add("column1value", "column2value", "etcvalue");
```

Comment: And how would I do it if I need to fill this datarow from SQL?

Comment: You should be able to use the same Fill method assuming your SQL query returns only a single row.